# Outputting custom field content as a ul in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, html-lists, custom-fields

Is there a way to have a custom field in wordpress output as an unordered list?

Using this code as a reference, it is outputting each word as a separate list item, is there a way to instead tell it to use a comma or another character as a way to break the list?

[Wordpress - output custom field as ul list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913825/wordpress-output-custom-field-as-ul-list)

Im very new to PHP.

```
 <?php
$list_items = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'idid', true);

     if($list_items){
        $list_items2 = explode(" ", $list_items);
            echo '<ul>';
                foreach($list_items2 as $list_item)
                    echo '<li>' . $list_item . '</li>';
            echo '</ul>';

    }

?>
```

Comment: Try to put all the resources in this page. Don't add a link to somehwer else, so people won't get lost.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want an HTML unordered list. You just want to output the list in a certain way, using a separator for instance. That's very basic:

```
<?php
$list_items = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'idid', true);
     if($list_items){
        $list_items2 = explode(" ", $list_items);
        $sep = ""              
        foreach($list_items2 as $list_item) {
            echo $sep . $list_item;
            $sep = ", ";  // this can be any char or string, or number...etc.
        }


    }

?>
```

Comment: Forgot the $ sign. Many years with no PHP programing.

Comment: also need to add ; at the end of $sep =""

Answer (score 0):

getting closer...but its putting a comma after every word. I want to have a sentence and then be able to put comma after the sentence so that it puts the next sentence on the line below it.

So, I'd type this in the custom field:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,Consectetur adipiscing elit,Quisque euismod lectus vitae commodo sollicitudin

And it would output this:

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
- Consectetur adipiscing elit Quisque
- Euismod lectus vitae commodo sollicitudin